# sql: how to join on a field that results from computation

Tags: sql, join

Is it possible to join on a field that isn't in a table, but is derived from it?

For example, if I have one table mapping calendar dates to data, and another mapping days of the week (0-6) to data.  How would one join the calendar dates table to the days of week table without adding a "day of week" field to the former?

Comment: You haven't said which flavour of SQL you're using - Mysql, Postgresql, oracle, SQL Server etc.

Comment: It's mysql.  See my comment on KM's answer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this:

```
select
    a.one+a.two, b.three
    from TableA           a
        inner join TableB b on a.one+a.two=b.three
```

just put your calculation in the join, index usage is unlikely though.  you don'y say your database, but if you have some command to take the weekday() of the date, you can join on that:

```
inner join TableB on weekday(a.EventDate)=b.Weekday
```

Comment: I'm using mysql with innodb.  Definitely hoping to make use of the indexes - should I just add a day of week field to the other table?

Comment: if you are only joining to a table with 7 rows (for the days of the week) then the index won't be used.  With so few rows, it is faster/easier to just scan the entire table.  However if you try to display just rows for a certain week day (like Tuesday) then the lack of an index will be noticed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL server, you can use the DATEPART function to give you which day of the week (0-7) a particular date is on. You should be able to join the date column using this function and your day of the week number:

```
select * from
t1 inner join t2 on
DATEPART(weekday,t1.dateColumnName) = t2.dayOfTheWeek
```

A gotcha though - this may vary dependant on which day of the week is set as the first in your SQL Server settings.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not.

```
select foo.dayofweek, bar.date from foo
join bar on datepart(dw, bar.date) = foo.dayofweek
```

Don't think this will leverage your indexes though, as the other guy said.